# intersection of normal lines converge to a point

Tags: differential-geometry

I have some difficulty working this out. Let $\alpha: I\rightarrow R^2$ be a regular parametrized plane curve(arbitrarily parameter), and define n=n(t) and k=k(t). Assume k(t) is not 0 for $t\in I$. We define $\beta(t)=\alpha(t)+\frac{n(t)}{k(t)},t\in I$. I can show that the tangent at t of $\beta$ is normal to $\alpha$ at t. But I don't know how to show for two neighboring points $t_1, t_2$, as $t_1$ approaches $t_2$, the intersection points of the normals converge to a point on the trace of $\beta(t)$. I think we can use the conclusion that the intersection of the normals are actually the intersection of tangents of $\beta(t)$. As $t_1$ approaches $t_2$, well you can kind of feel the intersection converges to $\beta(t_2)$ if you draw a picture but I don't know how to rigorously show it. I'll appreciate any help.